# No such Token-StripeError

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error can anyone please help to know what am doing wrong?

> Stripe \ Error \ InvalidRequest No such token:
>   tok_1E6AbPFWwEbVuzsrPEO3KM3A

**\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php**

```
// for API versions earlier than 2015-09-08
            if ($code == 'rate_limit') {
                return new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            }
            if ($type == 'idempotency_error') {
                return new Error\Idempotency($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            }

            // intentional fall-through
        case 404:
            return new Error\InvalidRequest($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 401:
            return new Error\Authentication($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 402:
            return new Error\Card($msg, $param, $code, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 403:
            return new Error\Permission($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 429:
            return new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        default:
            return new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
    }
}
```

Comment: The token id is invalid and does not exist in Stripe. You might copy it wrong from somewhere. If you are sure it is valid, you could write to Stripe and provide your account details and they can help you there.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using the right publish and secret key. But am not sure what you mean by copying it wrong from somewhere.

Comment: what I mean is where did you get this token `tok_1E6AbPFWwEbVuzsrPEO3KM3A`. This token seems not existing in Stripe's system, that's normally the error indicates. 
There might be a typo somewhere if you are copying the token

Answer (score 0):

this issue occur when you are generating token from different publish key and using different secret key to charge.
so when you try to charge or perform any action using that token which doesn't exists on the account which you are using of different account.
in that case stripe fire error "that token does not exist on you account ".
PLEASE verify you are using same publish and secret key

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i am using the right publish and secret key, but am still getting the error.